# MySQL doesn't use my index while it declares it will in explain statement

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I recently encounter a problem involving MySQL DBSM.
The Table is like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE `orders` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
`age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`sex` enum('男','女') DEFAULT NULL,
`amount` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `name_i` (`name`),
KEY `sex` (`sex`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5000001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

As is shown above ,I create a single colume index on col `name`
I want to perform a range query on `name`, and the explain statement is

```
mysql> explain select * from orders where name like '王%';
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+-------+----------+----------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra                            |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+-------+----------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | orders | NULL       | range | name_i        | name_i | 183     | NULL | 20630 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using MRR |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+-------+----------+----------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.10 sec)
```

so it should use the index `name_i` and finish the query in a flash(my classmate spent 0.07 sec)
however , this is how it turned out:

```
| 4998119 | 王缝   |   27 | 男   | 159.21 |
| 4998232 | 王求葬 |   19 | 男   | 335.65 |
| 4998397 | 王倘予 |   49 | 女   | 103.39 |
| 4998482 | 王厚   |   77 | 男   | 960.69 |
| 4998703 | 王啄淋 |   73 | 女   | 458.85 |
| 4999106 | 王般埋 |   70 | 女   | 700.98 |
| 4999359 | 王胆具 |   31 | 女   | 362.83 |
| 4999510 | 王铁脾 |   31 | 女   | 973.09 |
| 4999880 | 王战万 |   59 | 女   | 127.28 |
| 4999928 | 王忆   |   42 | 女   |  72.47 |
+---------+--------+------+------+--------+
11160 rows in set (3.43 sec)
```

And it seems to not use the index at all, because the data is sorted by the primary key `id` rather than col `name`(besides it is too slow ,comparing to 0.07 sec).

Has anyone encountered the problem too?

Comment: You can try use ‘force index’

Comment: `SELECT *` means that when the DB engine hits the leaves of the index it might have to do another seek to the clustered index to find data for the rest of the columns.  That is, MySQL may choose to not even use the index because it won't help.  There is also the issue of cardinality, and if many records begin with `王` then MySQL also may decide to not use the index and just scan.

Comment: To find out if it really uses the key, remove it and try again. If performance stays the same, it looks like it doesn't use it. Comparing to your class mate might not be useful: how many data does he have, on what hardware? Also, the ordering is undefined without `ORDER BY`, so you cannot say it uses the primary key when it is ordered by that column.

Comment: Regarding the apparent sort order on the `id` column, if `id` is the clustered index, then the order you see may just correspond to the physical order of the actual records, as MySQL scanned them into the result set. It doesn't necessarily mean that MySQL actually did some kind of explicit sort.

Comment: The order of result presentation is not proof that the index was used, nor is it proof that the index was ignored. Always use an `order by` clause to get a result in a required sequence.

Comment: so is there a case where MySQL claims it will use some index while it doesn't? I thought MySQL would perform exactly as it claims in explain statement.

Comment: I remove the index `name_i`and this time it spent 2.56 sec...even faster.In response to Mr. Biegelesien, I share the same data with my classmate as we all get it from our teacher. The table has 5000000  rows in total. Besides, why stackoverflow doesn't allow me to respond someone commenting under my question directly, it's not convenient

Comment: I added the index back and tried `order by name` .Guess what, it spent 1 min 32.24sec ... I'm totally confused.

Comment: @LoganXu - Stackoverflow does not _yet_ allow you to do a lot of things.  Take the 'tutorial'; that will give you 100 Reputation points; this will let you do a few more of the basic things.

Answer (score 1):

- What percentage of the table is "Kings" (王) ?  If it is more than about 20%, it will choose to do a table scan instead of use the index.  (And this may actually be faster.)  (Based on Comments, 0.22% of the table is Kings.)
- `EXPLAIN` and the execution of the query are separate things.  Although I don't remember proving this, it is *possible* that the `EXPLAIN` might say one thing, but the query would work another way.
- Do you have 5 million rows in the table?  Was the cache 'cold' when you first ran it?  And it had to fetch 11,160 rows from disk?  Then the second time, all was in cache, so much faster?
- Was the table loaded in "alphabetical" (or whatever the Chinese word for that is) order?  If so, there is a good chance the ids *and* the names are in the same order?
- Apparently you are using `utf8_general_ci` `COLLATION`?  *Maybe* it does not sort Chinese well.  (Provide a test case; I'll do some tests.)
- I do not understand why it mentioned `MRR`.
- I, too, am baffled by "1 min 32.24sec".  The `ORDER BY name` should have further encouraged the Optimizer to use `INDEX(name)`.  Can you turn on "Optimizer trace".

To really see whether it used the index, do this:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

If the big number(s) look like the number of rows in the table, then it did a table scan.  If they look more like 11160, then they used the index.

Comment: (I added some more thoughts.)